# How to check if user is already logged-in in pyrogram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-api, pyrogram

while trying to run a pyrogram script, how to check user is already logged-in in pyrogram or that session is valid ?

So we no need to login again and we can go on next step without login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to check if your connection to Telegram has not expired or if it was done successfully.

```
from pyrogram import errors
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(
    ...
)

app.connect()

try:
    app.get_me()
except (
        errors.ActiveUserRequired,
        errors.AuthKeyInvalid,
        errors.AuthKeyPermEmpty,
        errors.AuthKeyUnregistered,
        errors.AuthKeyDuplicated,
        errors.SessionExpired,
        errors.SessionPasswordNeeded,
        errors.SessionRevoked,
        errors.UserDeactivated,
        errors.UserDeactivatedBan,
        ):
    print("Session invalid / Login failed")
else:
    print('Login successfully')

app.disconnect()
```

Chers